# How to serve files stored in FTP space

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.Net MVC application allows you to download files that are stored in a repository accessible via FTP.

I would need to implement the best strategy to serve these files to the client. I could implement a method that downloads the file from FTP and then serves the file through FileResult ... but clearly it does not seem the best way at all (especially in the case of large files the client should first wait for the application to download the file and then wait a second time for the time necessary for the download).

Any indication or help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the web server can only access the files over FTP, then that's the way to go.

If the files are on a different server, your web server needs to download them from there (either entirely or streaming) before it can serve them to its HTTP clients.

Alternatively both servers could share the same file location, either by attaching the same (virtual) disk or through another network protocol such as NFDlS, SMB, ...

Comment: File are stored in object storage and we can access via FTP only. Is there a way to start serving the file without waiting for it to complete the download? I mean something like starting to serve the stream while downloading the stream from FTP  (in order to avoid the latency due to the first download)

Comment: Yes, using streams.

Comment: Can I ask you the favor of giving me a minimum example? With the following code I can recover the file from the FTP ... but I should serve the streming during the download:

   FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mylocation/test/bigfile.zip");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

 request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't find any way to indent or format my code sample in a better way :-((